# How to add JavaScript function to c#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm building a program in c# that includes google maps. I am trying to add a function that adds info window to a map according to user's insert. The problem is I have only found a JavaScript code function (that not completely suits) but I don't know how to add it to c#.
What I need is a way to connect the JS function, or a new c# function that fits.
This is the JS function I've found:

```
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map,
        title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Here is the result: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: You probably shouldn't be adding it to C# code. C# is server and javascript is (in your case) client. You need to have this in a separate .js file and include it in your web page(s).

Comment: Are you using C#.NET Webforms?

Answer (score 1):

Well I Don't Know Much About Javascript but I know a way which can help you out if you are using **C#.NET**:

```
public void sayHello()
{
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello World!')</script>");
}
```

or you can do as follows if you want to make a form for google maps in [**C#**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36151/Show-Your-Data-on-Google-Map-using-C-and-JavaScrip)

```
private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
{
String Locations = "";
foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
 {
   // bypass empty rows 
    if (r["Latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
        continue;

      string Latitude = r["Latitude"].ToString();
      string Longitude = r["Longitude"].ToString();

   // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record 
    Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay
     (new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
}

// construct the final script
js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
               function initialize() {
              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                 var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.5,-0.1167), 2); 
               " + Locations + @"
              map.setUIToDefault();
               }
           }
     </script> ";
}
```